# Activating Informix variables on Apache2/Debian

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, pdo, informix

I'm working on adding PDO for Informix on my Debian server.  I have a strong set of instructions from a gentleman who has set this up to run on suse, I'm trying to figure out how to add these variables to apache2 on debian.  For example, the instructions I'm working with have the following directions;

```
APACHE_EXTENDED_STATUS="off"

INFORMIXDIR=/myifx/csdk
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/myifx/csdk/lib:/myifx/csdk/lib/esql:/myifx/csdk/lib/client:/myifx/csdk/lib/cli:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Are these kinds of settings added to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are shell environment variables. Therefore, you should invoke them on your system shell. To get them set everytime you login, you should add these lines to your user's `.bash_profile` if you're using `bash`.

Update:

SuSE is quite special in this regard. /etc/sysconfig/apache2 is a SuSE specific file that controls e.g. apache modules to load, but also shell environment variables being passed to apache. To do this on a Debian system (pass shell environment variables to apache), you should take a look at the apache documentation for mod_env:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html

The `SetEnv` directive should do the trick.

If you want to set these vars on apache server level and not only for one vhost, there should also be an /etc/apache2/envvars on Debian where you can put these variables.

Comment: Odd.  In the suse instructions I've been looking at (and I fully admit that I don't know much about suse), it says that these are apache settings configured under /etc/sysconfig (see this link and look at step 7 specifically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909075/php-and-informix-on-debian-how-to-install-configure-the-pdo ).  Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: I've updated my answer.